# Adding git submodules?

Tags: git, svn

I'm trying to use an svn repository via git-svn, and I've added the svn externals as git submodules.

It looks like this has staged the submodule directories though, and I don't want to commit them back to svn.

I've tried adding them to .gitignore and using:

```
$ git reset HEAD
```

to unstage them, but now they no longer show up when I enter:

```
$ git submodule
```

Is this correct? Can I add svn externals as git submodules without committing them back to svn?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The only git-svn tool which supports this is **[SubGit](http://subgit.com/)** (as mentioned in "[Using git submodules in a `git-svn` project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10567905/6309)" or "[The story of Git, Git-Submodule and a SVN server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13957196/6309)", by [Dmitry Pavlenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1212681/dmitry-pavlenko), the main creator of SubGit).

Otherwise, you have to:

- [remove your submodule from the master branch](http://subgit.com/)
- declare those submodules in a dedicated branch (one which isn't `master`)

The idea would be to:

- work in that dedicated branch
- cherry-pick your new commits (ie any commmit which isn't the one adding submodules) back to master
- `git svn dcommit` from master (a branch with your commits copied from the dedicated branch, but free of any submodule declaration)